# C# My WebAPI has commands that generates a html file etc that works while running in VS, but if I host it in IIS Manager I get a 500 error?

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-web-api

If I run the WebAPI from Visual Studio, executing the command works just fine but after hosting it on IIS it generates a 500.

Other basic commands that doesn't involve writing to the computer work fine though (Get PUT etc).

Here's a picture of the configuration I set up.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVRpK.png

When I click test settings everything checks out.

Here's the code.  My only guess is I can't use C:\ directly and have to use something like %localhost% or some such, but not sure how to type that.

```
// GET: api/Report
    public void Get()
    {
        Process proc = null;

            string batDir = string.Format(@"C:\database_backup");
            proc = new Process();
            proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = batDir;
            proc.StartInfo.FileName = "agrisimdb.bat";
            proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
            proc.Start();
            proc.WaitForExit();


            //Launch Folder
            Process.Start(@"C:\database_backup");


    }

    // GET: api/Report/5
    public void Get(string id)
    {
        connection = detail.setConnection();

        connection.Open();

        DateTime d = DateTime.Parse(id);
        string date = d.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
        date = date.Replace('"', ' ').Trim();
        string sqlString = "SELECT purchaseID as 'Purchase ID', userID as 'User ID', p_time as Time, p_totalweight as 'Weight', p_totalprice as 'Price' FROM purchasetbl where p_date = '"+date+"'";
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sqlString, connection);
        var nullCheck = cmd.ExecuteScalar();

        string sqlString2 = "SELECT buyerID as 'Buyer', userID as 'User ID', receiver as 'Received By', s_totalweight as 'Weight', s_totalprice as 'Price' FROM saletbl where s_date = '"+date+"'";


        if (nullCheck != null)
        {
            dataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(sqlString, connection);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dataAdapter.Fill(dt);

            dataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(sqlString2, connection);
            DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
            dataAdapter.Fill(dt2);

            string htmlbody = ExportData(dt, dt2, date);
            //string filename = "exportdata2";
            string filename = "Daily Report "+date;
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"c:\htmltest\" + filename + ".HTML", htmlbody);
            Process.Start(@"C:\htmltest");
        }
        connection.Close();
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's just root, so type / for your home directory.  Also, what's the error message associated with your 500?

Comment: Has any error been logged to the Application Event Log?

Comment: 500 Errors are probably the worst error to debug.  They typically do not write anything to the Application Log as it's an error that isn't generated by your program, it's the server telling you there's something wrong with your configuration and consequently your software cannot be loaded and run.  Post the contents of your web.config file, usually the problem can be found there.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/6yNiUhyg Here's the error message that's returned  It's a "500 Internal Server Error".  (I use a Restlet Client to test the commands.  Oh and just to mention this API is just meant to be a localhost thing with the ability to allow external requests via mobile when a mobile is connected on the same local network.  (And everything works from visual studio, except for generating an html file or opening a folder when I place the WebAPI on the IIS manager)

Comment: The error is "Access Denied", apparently the program does not have access to the folder where you want to write the files.  Change the permissions on the folder to allow "Everyone" to read and write to the folder.  You can tighten up security later after you get it working.